# Odd functions.php issue in Wordpress

Tags: custom-field, functions, customization

I'm using More Fields plugin, and when I use my functions.php to embed the custom field, I get an odd issue. The field value is followed by a "1"

I use this code:

```
//Address
add_action( 'woo_post_inside_before', 'my_address' );
function my_address() {
    global $post;
if ( is_single() && in_category('listings') ) { 
        echo more_fields('address', '<h1>','</h1>');
       }
}
```

But, if I use the following code - their is no "1"

```
//Address
add_action( 'woo_post_inside_before', 'my_address' );
function my_address() {
    global $post;
if ( is_single() && in_category('listings') ) { 
        echo meta('address');
       }
}
```

How do I style the above using the echo meta? Or has anyone ever seen the "1" issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no WordPress function called `meta()`. Try using `get_post_custom()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom)) instead. For example:

```
//Address
add_action( 'woo_post_inside_before', 'my_address' );
function my_address() {
    if ( is_single() && in_category('listings') ) { 
        global $post;
        $meta = get_post_custom();
        echo '<h1>' . $meta['address'] . '</h1>';
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not sure you need to call `global $post;` in this context?

EDIT: updated to add HTML tags.

Comment: @chip-bennett - Hey Chip, how do I style it with css tags, classes, etc. such as my h1 example above? (wanting to do it all from functions.php, obviously i could style in the template, but I'm trying to avoid that)

Comment: Simply add the HTML tags to the echo command. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

[`more_fields()` already echos the output for you](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/more-fields/tags/2.0rc2/more-fields-template-functions.php#L4), you don't have to do this yourself. It returns a boolean indicating whether it could output anything, which is converted to `1` when you echo it.

So just call `more_fields()`, not `echo more_fields()` to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hunch because I do not know that plugin, your adding styling tags into the parameters of that function, I doubt that is possible (it might be though).

What happens when you use `echo more_fields('address')`

What about `echo "<h1>" . more_fields('address') . "</h1>";`

Or even better:

`<h1> <?php more_fields('address'); ?> </h1>`

Comment: echo more_fields still returns a "1".

Comment: echo "<h1>.... returns the "1" in the h1 tags but the value is returned without styling

Comment: and the other, I'm not sure how to call that correctly within my functions.php